# Special ImageFilter

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

Please have a look at the image attached. It's a small part of a matrix generated by reading in a larger 16bit image. 
I want to devise a filter so that all the non-zero values get the value of the most frequent number I was thinking to use a modal filter which will pick the mode(most frequent number in a kernel overlap) but it won't work for the non-zero numbers at the edges because then 0 would be the mode. Any ideas? It would be better if I find such a filter in Emgu CV library[image: Showing only 8x7 pixels of a larger image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response.
I found a very good way to do this.

1. Take a mask m out of the original Image object 'img'. The mask m tells us which pixels are zeros and which are non-zeros.
2. Dilate the image object by imgNew = img.Dilate(1) in emgu CV. The dilate function dilates the pixels by spreading the maximum value in the original image which overlaps with the dilate kernel. In the case above, the value 1056 replaces other smaller values such 304, 320, 272 etc. These values are spread further away from the center.
3. Since we now have more non-zero pixels due to dilation. One can multiply the imgNew with the mask m through the command cvInvoke.cvMul(imgNew.Ptr, mask.Ptr, imgNew.Ptr, 1);
4. The result is then as shown in the figure below
   [image]

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it can be done by simple filter instead I would do this:

1. compute histogram

   - create and set to zero integer counter per each possible color
   - loop through all pixels (x,y) and increment used color counter

     ```
     int i,x,y,cnt[65536];
     for (i=0;i<65536;i++) cnt[i]=0;
     for(y...)
      for(x...)
       cnt[pixel[y][x]]++;
     ```
2. pick the most common nonzero color

   - just find max number in `cnt[]` ignoring index 0
   - found index `ix` is the color
3. replace non-zero pixels with that color

   - just replace each zero pixel

     ```
     for(y...)
      for(x...)
       if (pixel[y][x]!=0)
        pixel[y][x]=ix;
     ```

[notes]

- pseudo code is in C++
- change the `for(x/y...)` for the correct image boundaries
- change `pixel[y][x]` for correct image pixel access

Comment: @umair heh just relized you want exact opposite that I have wrote (set the non zero pixels instead of zero pixels) have edited ... (just add `non` and  `!=`) ps your approach is fine too (for such type of images)

Comment: Thanks Spektre for the response. This approach of mine is very fast because one doesn't need to go to the pixel level himself because pixel lever operations slow it down.